# Inserting an integerValue into a dictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, dictionary, integer, xcode4.5

I want to get some value from a textfield and convert into a integer.

```
NSMutableDictionary* dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic setValue:txtTable.text forKey:@"Table"];
```

I tried to use this but it doesn't work:

```
[dic setValue:[txtTable.text integerValue] forKey:@"Table"];
```

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSInteger intVal = [txtTable.text integerValue];
dict[@"Table"] = @(intVal);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the integer value in an NSNumber value.

```
NSInteger val = [txtTable.text integerValue];
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:val];
[dic setObject:num forKey:@"Table"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSNumber`. It can wrap an integer value and can be added in `array` or `dictionary`.

**Update:**
`NSNumber` is subclassed from `NSValue`. So you can use it for wrapping it as mentioned in some of the answers as,

```
[dic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[txtTable.text integerValue]] forKey:@"Table"];
```

This can be added to arrays or dictionaries. To fetch it back you can use `[[dic valueForKey:@"Table"] integerValue]`.

For wrapping `CGRect`, `CGSize` or `CGPoint` you can use [`NSValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: That won't work for a textfield, since it only stores NSString.

Comment: Looks like NSNumber is sufficient. NSNumber is subclassed from NSValue.

Comment: @Ryan, I didnt get what you meant.

Comment: @ACB - what does NSValue have to do with putting a value in a dictionary? You can put NSString objects in a dictionary. You can put other dictionaries in a dictionary. Neither of those are NSValue objects. You can put any custom object you want in a dictionary. It just needs to be an object.

Comment: NSValue can be used to wrap types such as CGRect, CGSize etc.. Since NSNumber can be used for wrapping integers, he can use that here. Check my update.

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer with that suggestion. In this scenario he doesnt need NSValue.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
[dic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[txtTable.text integerValue]] forKey:@"Table"];
```